# Is adding the newline character to printf() equivalent to flushing the stream?

Tags: c, printf

The following program shows how buffered I/O can cause problems in programs when errors like 'divide by zero' happen:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 0, c;

    printf("Dividing...");
    c = a/b;

    printf("Answer is: %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `Floating point exception (core dumped)`.

Fair enough. But surprisingly, if I changed the first printf to `printf("Dividing...\n");`, this text actually gets printed before the program crashes (I'm running GCC on Linux, by the way).

Am I to conclude that adding a newline is equivalent to flushing? And if so, if all my `printf()` strings end in `\n`, I'm actually depriving myself of the benefits of buffered I/O?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your standard output is going to a terminal, yes, it's equal to flushing, as `printf()` will use line-based buffering.

If it's redirected to a file, then no. In this case `printf()` uses much bigger buffers, usually corresponding to file system block sizes or whatever, to optimize IO.

Comment: Amazing answer, and I must say, an amazing revelation! :D