# Printf not printing immediately, although buffering is disabled

Tags: c, linux, printf, buffer, raspberry-pi3

I'm having problem with the printf function in C. It's just not printing the output, although buffering is disabled:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

and

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

also I'm using `fflush(stdout);`, but it still doesn't work.
This is the exact code:

```
int setup(){
    //...
    printf("Setup successful\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setup();
    //...
)
```

If the info helps; I'm on Linux (raspberry Pi).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to show [mcve] of your code if you expect an answer.

Comment: Both variants should work (either fflush(stdout) or setbuf(stdout, NULL)). 
Do you compile it correctly (e.g. with gcc -o printtest printtest.c) and call it from the local directory like so: ./printtest ?  (If you omit the ./ then you are not calling your program from the local directory instead you are calling something else that is in the path)

Comment: "The function setvbuf() returns 0 on success. It returns nonzero on failure (mode is invalid or the request cannot be honored). It may set errno on failure."

Comment: Do you set the stream to unbuffered at the beginning of execution / before any other printf calls? -"The setvbuf() function may only be used after opening a stream and before any other operations have been performed on it." The same holds for setbuf().

Comment: Can you show your code to verify whether it's printf fault or you execution flow doesnot reach there. fflush(stdout) should definitely flush your output.

Comment: The two functions are directly executed on startup, setvbuf() returns 0. The print-function is executed by a function which is called by the main function. As if this wasn't strange enough, sometimes the printing works even without calling setbuf / setvbuf immediately.

Comment: Posting a [mcve] would help.  It is unclear why a complete compilable code is not posted with a question with a bounty.

Comment: If this didn't have a bounty, it would be closed because it lacks an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We cannot diagnose the problem without seeing your main program.  The call to `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()` must be the first operation on the file stream.

Comment: @itzFlubby Don't describe the code, **show** the code.  Describing code says "this is *basically* what I'm telling the computer to do".  Problem is, computers don't do "basically" what you tell them.  They do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you're telling the computer to do, i.e. show the code as a [mcve] that others can compile and run that replicates your problem.

Comment: I added the exact code now. Sorry.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with this code.  If you copy and paste the above code *as is*, compile it and run it, does it reproduce the issue on your side?

Comment: Strangely it does. I use the IDE Geany to make the program. If I run the program via the IDE, it behaves this way (not always when I execute the program from the terminal). But after I ran the program, the terminal also doesn't  flush anymore, if you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve tried reproducing your setup as closely as possible. I therefore installed Raspbian (The Raspberry Pi operating system) in a VirtualBox image and used Geany to create, compile and execute a C file. Here is the code in its entirety:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Setup successful\n");
}
```

1. Save this file as `test.c`:

   [image: test.c saved]
2. Next, click on “Build” (the brick icon):

   [image: build test.c]
3. And finally, run it (click on the paper plane icon):

   [image]

As you can see, this code compiles correctly, executes, and prints the message. No explicit flushing is necessary ([`printf` to stdout automatically flushes when encountering a newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22385671/1968)). This behaviour is standardised and correctly implemented by the tools installed by Raspbian so it’s reliable.

Comment: First of all respect for your great effort. Does the same output appear if you run an endless loop directly after the printing?. Like `printf("test\n"); while(1){}`

Comment: @itzFlubby Yes: the buffer is flushed immediately after encountering the `'\n'`. The output is a single “test” on the terminal. — Is this not the case for you?

Comment: No, it then doesn't flush.

Comment: Could it have something to do that the program is compiled with the `-g` flag for debugging?

Comment: @itzFlubby I’m afraid not, `-g` won’t change the behaviour of this.

Comment: So you indirectly answered me that there is a specific problem with my system (Maybe a false setting, corrupt package, ...) and showed clearly that there should be no problem with the "normal" out-of-the-box-system. This is why I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: @itzFlubby Apologies for not being able to help better, I know this must be frustrating. But in summary you’re right: this problem must be elsewhere.